# How to load a bootstrap modal just click on a wordpress plugin submenu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

My modal is working fine if i add a button or link in my plugin submenu page to trigger the modal. But i want to load my modal on clicking on the submenu.When i clicked on the submenu it calls a function and tried using some javascript in those function to load it on page load.I have tried below options on my function head but not working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).load(function(){
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
  });
</script>
```

aslo this i tried:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#memberModal').modal('show');
});
```

Can anyone help me with identifying my problem. I have searched already almost every possible solution.But what i think my problem is here the javascript is not loading in time thats why i am having this problem. But dont know how to fix this.

If anyone nedds so my whole function code is given below:

```
<?php
function sfb_create_form_page(){

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(window).load(function(){
     $('#myModal').modal('show');
   });
</script>
<!-- Modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog">

<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title"><h3>Choose Your Form</h3></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <a href="#tabs" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal" id="modal_trigger">Click</a>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>   
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <!--  Modal Tab Content -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="tabs"  tabindex="-1">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="icon-xs-o-md"></i></button>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title caps"><strong>Design Your Form</strong></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <!-- Modal Body Here -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabContent">
        <li class="active"><a href="#details" data-toggle="tab"><strong>HTML For Form</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="#access-security" data-toggle="tab"><strong>Edit Form Content</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="#networking" data-toggle="tab"><strong>Button Style</strong></a></li>
    </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="details">
      <!-- Tab 1 Content Goes Here -->
    </div><!-- Tab 1 Ends Here -->

    <div class="tab-pane" id="access-security">
    <!-- Tab 2 Content Goes Here -->
    </div> <!-- Tab 2 Ends Here -->


    <div class="tab-pane" id="networking">
    <!-- Tab 1 Content Goes Here -->
    </div> <!-- Tab 3 Ends Here -->
  </div><!--  Ends of Tab-->
 </div><!-- End of Body -->
   <div class="modal-footer">  <!-- Fooetr -->          
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="">OK</button>
   </div> <!--End of Fooetr -->  
 </div> <!-- End of modal content -->
 </div><!-- End of modal Dialouge -->
</div><!-- End of Modal Tab -->
<?php
}// End of create page function
```

Comment: you need a click function. ($(document).on("click", "#mybutton-id", function(){ $('#myModal').modal('show'); }))

Comment: Can u please give code according to my function? I am very new to this so i am having this silly problem

Comment: You want to show the modal after the page loads in?? if so, forget the click function. At the bottom of the Page after everything (after </html>) just put (<script type="text/javascript">$('#myModal').modal('show');</script>) or give it a one 1 or 2 seconds time out function (<script type="text/javascript">setTimeout(function(){ $('#myModal').modal('show'); }, 1000);</script>)

Comment: @TasosAnastasiou here what do you mean by `#mybutton-id`? Where from this is coming? I cant get it.Sorry for silly question.

Comment: check my 2nd comment, if i understand your question right, you are trying to show the modal after page load. is that correct??

Comment: Tried but not working. i add the script at the bottom of my function but still the same output.

Comment: Yes that is correct. And what you said i think this should work bt not

Comment: Ok as a test let the page load. Open the browsers console and paste in ($('#memberModal').modal('show');) and hit enter. does it open?? or do you get an error

Comment: It shows 'SyntaxError: missing ) in parenthetical'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78137/discussion-between-bashar-and-tasos-anastasiou).

Comment: Sorry No time at the moment -- just run  $('#memberModal').modal('show'); in the console

Answer (score 1):

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Aramil/jtycsrmn/)

Just use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

And remember, its REALLY important to call first JQuery, and then Bootstrap.min.js

Comment: Ray I have enqueued my JQuery, and Bootstrap.min.js in the `init` hook. Can you please check my code and tell me where i have put this script in my code? I have tried on both head of my functio and bottom but not working

Comment: If i use it in a `HTML` file then its working just fine. But when i am using in my wordpress plugin then its not working